# Hibernate object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing

Tags: hibernate

Error:

```
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.SomeObject
```

Code:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "SOMEOBJECTID", nullable = true, insertable=true, updatable=true)
public SomeObject getSomeObject() {
    return this.someObject;
}

public void setSomeObject(SomeObject someObject) {
    this.someObject= someObject;
}
```

I have a form where the various options someObject is required or not.

Unfortunately, I get an error as above

I tried also `CascadeType.ALL`, but

```
org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value: com.SomeObject
```

What is the cause? Apparently I set nullable = true (in the database as well), and even though I have this error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have a `Order` entity having `OneToMany` relationship with `OrderLine` entities. Now if you don't have `CASCADE` property set, then when you try to save an `Order` entity like this:

```
Order order = new Order();
OrderLine orderLine = new OrderLine();
order.setOrderLine(orderLine);
session.save(order);
```

then you will get an exception saying:

```
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing
```

To fix this you have to save the `OrderLine` before saving `Order`:

```
session.save(orderLine);
session.save(order);
```

Now if you have bi-directional relationship and also if you try to set the `CASCADE` property and do the same operation like this:

```
Order order = new Order();
OrderLine orderLine = new OrderLine();
order.setOrderLine(orderLine);
session.save(orderLine);
session.save(order);
```

then you will get an exception as :

```
org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value
```

because the `orderLine` has a property for `order` which is `null` in this case as we have not sets value. So to fix this you need to maintain the relationship properly on both sides by adding this extra line:

```
orderLine.setOrder(order);
```